# RowSizingAutoMaxLines one row Ultragrid Infragistics

Tags: c#, resize, row, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am using this code, it is a bad example, but it works to test, but it ends up changing all rows.

I need only change the row selected.

```
if (e.Cell.Column.Layout.Override.RowSizingAutoMaxLines == 4)
{
       e.Cell.Column.Layout.Override.RowSelectorStyle = Infragistics.Win.HeaderStyle.XPThemed;
       e.Cell.Column.Layout.Override.RowSizingAutoMaxLines = 20;
}
else
{
       e.Cell.Column.Layout.Override.RowSelectorStyle = Infragistics.Win.HeaderStyle.Default;
       e.Cell.Column.Layout.Override.RowSizingAutoMaxLines = 4;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the RowSizingAutoMaxLines on Override will set this to all the rows. What you can do instead is calculate the necessary row height and set it to the current row, assuming you have set beforehand [RowSizing](http://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics4.win.ultrawingrid.v16.2~infragistics.win.ultrawingrid.rowsizing) to Free or to AutoFree. You can use Graphics MeasureString to calculate the height of one row and set then each row's height like this:

First setup the grid:

```
    private void UltraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
{
    //  I think you need row selectors as you set their style
    e.Layout.Override.RowSelectors = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;

    //  Set the RowSizing to some Free value to allow each row to has its onw height
    e.Layout.Override.RowSizing = RowSizing.AutoFree;

    //  I think you have multiline text in the cells, so you should set CellMultiLine to true too
    e.Layout.Override.CellMultiLine = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
}
```

Then measure one row and set the row's height:

```
//  Calculate the height of one line of text
var oneLineHeight = float.MinValue;
using(Graphics g = this.ultraGrid1.CreateGraphics())
{
    oneLineHeight = g.MeasureString("Jj", this.ultraGrid1.Font, int.MaxValue, StringFormat.GenericTypographic).Height;

}

// Set the row selectors' style and the row's height
if(e.Cell.Column.Layout.Override.RowSelectorStyle == Infragistics.Win.HeaderStyle.Default)
{
    e.Cell.Column.Layout.Override.RowSelectorStyle = Infragistics.Win.HeaderStyle.XPThemed;

    //  Add 4 to add some padding
    e.Cell.Row.Height = (int)(oneLineHeight * 20 + 4);
}
else
{
    e.Cell.Column.Layout.Override.RowSelectorStyle = Infragistics.Win.HeaderStyle.Default;

    //  Add 4 to add some padding
    e.Cell.Row.Height = (int)(oneLineHeight * 4 + 4);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to apply these properties only for selected row. where  `UltraGrid1_InitializeLayout` event code apply for overall ultragrid.